# Using Flask-Socketio with Tensorflow model causes model to error on predict

Tags: tensorflow, keras, flask-socketio

I am trying to run a model with saved weights in my python flask-socketio server.  When I run the application, as far as I can tell the weights are loaded correctly.  When I run the front-end, which emits an event and causes the model to issue a prediction on the backend side I get an error.  I would expect the prediction to be sent back to the front-end so that I can update the display.

This is using a flask-socketio backend and socket.io on the front end for an event-based communication.  I have tried numerous solutions that have worked for others using normal REST API's based in Flask but none have transferred over to flask-socketio.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np

def init():
    global model, graph
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(6,)))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='linear'))
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mae'])
    model.load_weights("training_1/cp.ckpt")
    model._make_predict_function()
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()

@socketio.on('start_play')
def handle_play(json, method=['GET', 'POST']):
    global graph

    if NEURAL_NET_PLAY:
        with graph.as_default():
            state = np.array([game.get_game_state_vector()])
            prediction = model.predict(state)
            if prediction == 0:
                game.time_step({'left' : True, 'right' : False})
            else:
                game.time_step({'left' : False, 'right' : True})

    else:
        game.time_step(json)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("running python server")
    global NEURAL_NET_PLAY
    NEURAL_NET_PLAY = True
    if NEURAL_NET_PLAY:
        init()
    socketio.run(app, debug=False)
```

The error message that I am receiving when I run this is:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable dense_2/bias from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/dense_2/bias/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist.
     [[{{node dense_2/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp}}]]
```

and in the stack trace it fails at model.predict.

Comment: Are you using eventlet with your Flask-SocketIO server? TensorFlow is likely incompatible with eventlet and other async frameworks. Mixing CPU inensive code with an asynchronous server is not likely to work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that this can be a problem with the flask thread, because Keras isn´t threadsafe. I ran into a similar problem when I wanted to use flask and keras a couple of month ago. Please check [this Snippet](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1728728). Maybe it helps you and gives you an solution.

You can find additional information [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5640).